# Kibana: Make phrase short yield no result

Tags: lucene, logstash, kibana

The original log looks like this:

```
{"@message":"INFO 2014-03-03 23:59:30,022 [automatic.notify.service.17] ...
```

If I search for `23:59:30,022` I can find the line, but if I search for `23:59:30`, no result get returned any explanation for this?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is looking for the exact match, you should try with `23:59:30*` if you do not care about miliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

What search pattern are you using in Kibana?

Basically:

```
@message="<string>"
```

looks for an exact match, while

```
@message:"<string>"
```

is a a pattern match

A Kibana (Lucene) query of

```
@message:"23:59:30"
```

Should work, although you may need to add a few more conditions to zone in on the exact line you are looking for.